# Display S3 images in wicked PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, wicked-pdf

I copied this question from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyonrails-talk/9Wfid1pYP7w/qqSIiW45L_8J
I have the same problem with him, please help me, thanks a lot

Hello Everyone,

I am using Wicked Pdf to generate pdf file.

In my model, i have method to generate pdf file.

I also need to show image in my pdf file from amazon s3.

Case 1:
  i tried using 
  While i am running that method image not displaying, just a small box only appearing insteat of image.

Case 2:
  i tried <%= image_tag(@image.avatar)%>
  While i run this, i am getting "rake aborted!
undefined method `image_tag' for main:Object"

i googled this problem but no clear answer... any help..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use wicked_pdf_image_tag to show images in pdf. Try it with some local image:
    `<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag "some_image.jpg" %>`

This should work.
Then try it with s3 image. If image doesn't show up, this mean that you using old version of wkhtmltopdf library. Download new version from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html